# UIVIew resizing in Storyboard and NIB difference

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview

community. There's some strange UIView resizing thing, that i can't understand.

Let's say, we have simple Single-View Application with Main.storyboard.
In storyboard i'm creating `RedView`. It has default size 600x600. And all options are set by default. I'm not changing anything.

Now, i am creating BlueView.xib with `BlueView`, and it has the same size and the same options as RedView. Also i am creating `BlueViewControler` class, and setting it as owner in BlueView.xib. BlueViewControler is empty.

RedView includes BlueView as a child like this:

```
@implementation RedViewController
{
    BlueViewController *_blueViewController;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _blueViewController = [[BlueViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BlueView" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:_blueViewController.view];
}

@end
```

And now, when i am launching application on iPhone 5 Simulator, RedView becomes 320 * 568, and Blue view becomes 600 * 600.

```
2015-08-28 13:32:17.937 TestViewSize[3087:77218] RedView frame = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
2015-08-28 13:32:17.938 TestViewSize[3087:77218] BlueView frame = {{0, 0}, {600, 600}}
```

On the screen they also look differently.
So my question is:

1. Why do RedView, created in storyboard, autoresizes? I can understand, why Blue view is 600*600, but why Red adjusts to screen size? Who tells it to do this?
2. What the difference between creating view in XIB and in storyboard **related to sizing views, not anything else.** Why do storyboard resize its view, and .XIB do not?

My project Created in Xcode 6, target is 8.0, using of `Autolayout` and `Size Classes` are enabled.

Comment: u have to override  any of init methods of `BlueViewController`and set frame when u create with nib

Comment: @muku , i know, how i can handle this, i'm interested in **why** is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Such an old question, but still someone might not quite understand such behaviour, like me when faced it firstly.

`UIViewController` in storyboard has option `"Resize View From NIB"`, while `UIView` in xib hasn't. By default this option is on, that makes view controller's view resized to screen size when loading, even before view is added to views hierarchy.

Comment: I have unchecked it and set simulated size to "free form 100x100" but my view when presented is always full screen or equal to current context.

Comment: @Adobels when you present UIViewController, it always finally takes size according to modal presentation style; i e if you present full screen, it'll have size equal to screen size.

Comment: ok, but what is a usage case for the „resize view from nib” uiviewcontroller option?

Comment: @Adobels It has meaning when you add view controller's view into views hierarchy manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is becaus of Size Classes According to apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)

> People generally want to use their favorite apps on all their devices and in any orientation. In iOS 8 and later, you use size classes and Auto Layout to help you meet this expectation by defining how the layout of screens, view controllers, and views should adapt when the display environment changes.

So when you test it on iPhone55 your redView which is storyboard has **wAnyhAny** resizes itself while blue view which you are adding as subView remians same. Now you haven't used any constarint to specify it's width or height si it's still 600x600

**EDIT**
[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) might be better

Comment: But my XIB file also has **wAnyhAny**, so why isn't it working in the same way?
Also, it's impossible to add constraints to XIB's top level view (pin menu is just empty). And i **didn't** add any constraints to storyboard, too. So these views are in the same situation, except they are created in different ways.

Comment: @Akira you are adding xib as subview of one another. If you want them as in same condition then you should try storyboard with two VC

Comment: I can add xib view directly to keyWindow, and effect will be the same: xib view still remains 600*600.
I don't need them to be in same condition, i need to know, why storyboard resizes it's view, and xib does not.